# Side input in Apache Beam streaming pipeline produces error "NoneType has no attribute max_timestamp"

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, pipeline, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I have a streaming pipeline windowed with a 10s fixed window.
When I reach this part of the code:

```
flatten = ((input_source1, input_source2, input_source3, input_source4) | beam.Flatten()
           | beam.Filter(filter_existing, existing=beam.pvalue.AsList(existing_timeline_input))
          )
```

I get a runtime error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'max_timestamp'"

Generated in /apache_beam/transforms/sideinputs.py", line 65, in map_via_end
window.WindowFn.AssignContext(source_window.max_timestamp())))[-1]

If I add a shuffle before the filter, like this:

```
flatten = ((input_source1, input_source2, input_source3, input_source4) | beam.Flatten()
           | beam.Reshuffle()
           | beam.Filter(filter_existing, existing=beam.pvalue.AsList(existing_timeline_input))
          )
```

Then it works and I get no errors.
Could you explain how would that be possible?

Thank you!

EDIT:

Some of those input_source are None.

- If I remove the None input sources, I do not get errors.
- If I print the resulting Pcollection after flatten, I do not see any None element
- If I use a constant instead of the AsList side input in the filter transform, I do not get any error.

EDIT2:

This is the rest of the code:

```
    start = (p | beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(topic=topic)
             | "decoding" >> beam.Map(lambda x: json.loads(x.decode()))
             | 'With timestamps' >> beam.Map(lambda user: beam.window.TimestampedValue(user, time.time()))
             | 'process User' >> beam.ParDo(
                processors.UserProcessor(project=project, region=region))
             | 'Window into Fixed Intervals' >> beam.WindowInto(beam.window.FixedWindows(10))
             )


input_source1 = (start| beam.ParDo(collectors.GeneralCollector(param)))

input_source2 = (start
                 | beam.ParDo(
            collectors.PersonalCollector(param)))

input_source3 = (start
                 | beam.ParDo(collectors.MyCollector()))

input_source4 = (start
                 | beam.ParDo(
            collectors.AuthoredCollector(project=project)))

existing_input = (start
                 | beam.ParDo(
            processors.ExistingEntriesProcessor(project=project, region=region))
                 | beam.Map(lambda x: x.get('id'))
                 )
```

Comment: Because you are in a Streaming pipeline, are you applying proper windowing to each input before joining them in a flatten? They should each have "compatible" windows like all fixed windows with same window size. See https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#flatten

Comment: Thanks for you answer Cubez. I have a main input pcollection USERS generated from pubsub, windowed with a fixed window of 10s. All the input_sourceN that are listed in the flatten are generated from USERS, so they should all share the same exact window.

Comment: It looks like your side input doesn't have an associated window for some reason. Can you post the rest of your code please?

Comment: I added the rest of the code. The pcollection start collects the users from the pubsub messages. All the other steps are using the user as input to collect other kind of data data.

Comment: did you figure out what was the root cause? thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately not